# In unix , moving a file with xargs after finding and zipping it?

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu

So in a bashscript i've the following very simple line , but how can i chain it further to move the file ?

```
find . -type f -ctime -$2 -name "mylog*.log" | xargs bzip2
```

This works fine but i'd also like to move the file to a new directory once I am done with the bzip2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One standard trick is to use a new script that does whatever you need.  Here, I assume that `${OTHER_DIRECTORY}` is an environment variable that says where to put the compressed files, but there are plenty of other (better!) ways to get that information to the script (such as specifying the directory as the first argument — as the last argument is a bad idea).

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$@"
do
    bzip2 "$file"
    mv "$file.bz2" "${OTHER_DIRECTORY:-/tmp}"
done
```

You then run that script with `find`:

```
find . -type f ctime -$2 -name "mylog*.log" -exec tinyscript.sh {} +
```

This is pretty effective.  If you only want one `mv` command, you can consider something along the lines of:

```
bzip2 "$@"
bz2=()
for file in "$@"; do bz2+=( "$file.bz2" ) done
mv "${bz3[@]}" "${OTHER_DIRECTORY:-/tmp}"
```

This code works even if the path names contain spaces and other untoward characters.

Comment: Thanks ,that seems to do it

Answer (score 1):

One option might be something like this:

```
find . -type f -ctime -$2 -name "mylog*.log" -exec bzip2 {} \; -exec mv {} /path/to/new_dir/ \;
```

Comment: The `mv` will get the old filename and fail, won't it?

Comment: I mean attaching .bz2 after {} does do the trick tough, even if its not completly clean.